# (OpenCV 2.4.6) Copy header of a Mat's roi to another Mat's roi

Tags: python, c++, c, opencv, memory

My question is about **how to copy only header of a roi of a Mat to another roi of a Mat** to avoid copying entire Mat's data for saving computation time.

For instance, I have a roi of a source Mat as

```
Mat src(cv::Size(4,3),CV_32FC1);
for(int i=0;i<src.rows;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<src.cols;j++){
    src.ptr<float>(i)[j] = i*src.cols+j;
  }
}
Mat src_roi = src(Rect(1,1,src.cols-2,src.rows-1));
cout << src << endl;
cout << src_roi << endl;

// = = = OUTPUT = = =
[0, 1, 2, 3;
 4, 5, 6, 7;
 8, 9, 10, 11]
[5, 6;
 9, 10]
```

Next, I expect the result shows as below with the key function (func()) as

```
Mat dst(cv::Size(src.cols*src.rows,1),CV_32FC1);
dst.setTo(-1);
Mat dst_roi = dst.colRange(2,2+src_roi.cols*src_roi.rows);
func(src_roi,dst_roi);
cout << dst << endl;
cout << dst_roi << endl;

// = = = OUTPUT = = =
[-1, -1, 5, 6, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Basically, the func() can be implemented as ways below for simply reaching my expected output (computation times are evaluated in release mode),

```
// A01 = = =
void func(const Mat &src,Mat &dst){
  Mat ma = src.clone();
  ma = ma.reshape(0,1);
  ma.copyTo(dst);
}
// = = = Computation time = = =
0.414 seconds // when src's size is changed to 15000*15000

// A02 = = =
void func(const Mat &src,Mat &dst){
  MatConstIterator_<float> it1 = src.begin<float>(), it1_end = src.end<float>();
  MatIterator_<float> dst_it = dst.begin<float>();
  for( ; it1 != it1_end; ++it1, ++dst_it ){
    *dst_it = *it1; 
  }
}
// = = = Computation time = = =
0.508 seconds // when src's size is changed to 15000*15000

// A03 = = =
void func(const Mat &src,Mat &dst){
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<src.rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<src.cols;j++){
      ((float*)dst.data)[count++] = src.ptr<float>(i)[j];
    }
  }
}
// = = = Computation time = = =
0.269 seconds // when src's size is changed to 15000*15000
```

However, they all copy entire matrix thus spend much time whenever the roi is large.

**Hence, I hope there is a way to copy only headers or pointers to reach the same effect as well as saving required computations. 
Or other ways or thoughts which could satisfy my expectation.**

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse in your func() you copy each elem two times (first src.clone() and copyTo()) so
what comes to my mind is to get rid of one od them by directly copying elems from src to dst:

```
void func(const Mat &src,Mat &dst){
    MatConstIterator_<float> it1 = src.begin<float>(), it1_end = src.end<float>();
    MatIterator_<float> dst_it = dst.begin<float>();

    for( ; it1 != it1_end; ++it1, ++dst_it )
        *dst_it = *it1; 
}
```

And you dont have to care what size the src and dst have but they have to have the same number of elements.

But frankly I think you can't avoid that one copy because the src and dst have different size formats. You can't do reshape() directly on src_roi because it is not continous. And this is what you expect, beacuse you cannot reshape a matrix which is a part of bigger one changing its format shape on some roi and not changing in whole matrix. I mean you cannot tell opencv to copy only headers roi if header have not the same size format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Moreover, I've added your suggestion into my question, and I also evaluate the computation time for comparison.

Comment: From what I know from official API, there is no posibility  to avoid copying in our case since  the crucial thing is when you would like to change matrix format ie from two dimensions to one dimension. In that case opencv would not allow to call reshape() on the src variable in func() beacuse reshape() affects the object itself (not that it returns a copy of other object) and moreover src in our func() it's already a roi croppped from bigger matrix. If your case would not contain changing matrix shape you could just assign dst = src; in func()

Comment: - and void copying. But still you have access to Mat::data pointer so there can exists some hack. If you get the answer, please let us know.

Comment: Indeed. But I see some potential technical possibilities since that it might be treated as existing roi implementation [`Mat::Mat(const Mat& m, const Rect& roi)`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp) with maybe some arrangements for locations. Yet, I dont fully get it thus desire some helps:(